# MG F MGF is my heater hose normal?

Tags: mg

I was working on my mgf tonight and after checking the jiggle valve in the engine bay, I saw this in the hose:

[image]

Yes i know it's very dirty and that's why i am working on it. My problem is that i don't remember have ever seen this thing in my hose. Was it there? If yes has it just rotate a bit? Is it completely normal?

This is a T hose section.

Thanks